# How to force a Python's function to accept a certain input?

Tags: python, function, methods, input

Regardless of whether it's a good idea or not, I wanted to know whether it would be possible to force a method to accept a certain input, for example a character without quotes ("!"). Exempli gratia:

```
def special_print(text):
    """Print <text> unless ! (no quotes!) is passed as argument."""
    if text == !:
        print("Easter egg!")
    else:
        print(text)


special_print("Hello, World"!)
>>> Hello, World!

special_print("!")
>>> !

special_print(!)
>>> Easter egg!
```

Would that be possible? Just curious.

Comment: Not unless you'd like to fork Python with your own syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible unless you make your own build of the Python source.

The only exception is for `...`, which equates to an `Ellipsis` object in Python 3 (not Python 2). So you could do:

```
def special_print(text):
    """Print <text> unless ... (no quotes!) is passed as argument."""
    if text == ...:
        print("Easter egg!")
    else:
        print(text)
```

`...` is designed to be used in slices, but as of Python 3 you can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible in the way you described, but I guess that you want to use that kind of syntax in the interactive shell, otherwise I can't even imagine how this can be useful. In this case writing your own shell with [cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module will be the way to go. For example:

```
import cmd

class SpecialPrint(cmd.Cmd):

    def do_print(self, line):
        print line

    def do_exit(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpecialPrint().cmdloop()
```

Running of this code will spawn a shell that works as follows:

```
(Cmd) print !
!
(Cmd) print anything you want
anything you want
(Cmd) exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of asking a different question in a roundabout way.  Python is dynamically typed, so a function will accept any type.  You can do something similar to what you want using other types, possibly using `Sentinel` objects.

```
Sentinel = object()

def special_print(text):
    if text is Sentinel:
        print("Easter egg!")
    else:
        print(text)

special_print(Sentinel)
```

You can't use a `!` character because that isn't a valid variable name.  You don't have to use `Sentinel` objects either, just use non-string variables

```
def special_print(text):
    if isinstance(text, int):
        print("Easter egg!")
    else:
        print(text)

special_print(1)
```